# Excel VBA - Print Selected Sheets to Multiple PDFs - Printing all sheets to single PDF -?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an Excel VBA PDF printer macro that should print each of the selected worksheets as individual PDFs. This was working as expected six months ago on a previous work machine, but now it's doing something that I don't understand. Now running Office 365, Excel version 2401, 64 bit.

For instance, if I have a workbook open that contains Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 and I want to print all three sheets as individual PDFs...

If I select the sheets in sequential order (Sheet1 then Sheet2 then Sheet3), I end up with three PDFs (the goal), BUT...

PDF1 contains Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 (not what I want).
PDF2 contains only Sheet2 (what I want)
PDF3 contains only Sheet3 (what I want)

[image]

If I select the sheets in NON-sequential order (Sheet2 then Sheet1 then Sheet3), I end up with three PDFs like I intended...

PDF2 contains only Sheet2
PDF1 contains only Sheet1
PDF3 contains only Sheet3

[image]

I also get the correct behavior, if I only want to print 2 of the 3 sheets.

I'm missing something. Can anyone point out why I'm getting this behavior?

Thanks!

```
Sub PDFSheets()
'==================================================================
' This subroutine will print the selected worksheets as
' a single (merged) or multiple PDF files.
'
' "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" may need to be Referenced when using FileSystemObjects
'==================================================================
'
    ' Check what Option Base (array index) setting is
    iBase = LBound(arrBase)
    
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    ' check if file is saved in SharePoint/OneDrive
    ' if it is, then use the computer's local drive folder
    ' instead of the web address
    If strPath = "" Then
        a = MsgBox("File path does not exist. Please save file and try again.", vbOKOnly, "PDF saving error")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf InStr(1, strPath, "sharepoint", 1) > 0 Then
        i = InStr(1, strPath, "Shared Documents/Jobs", 1)
        strPath = Right(strPath, Len(strPath) - i - Len("Shared Documents/Jobs") + 1)
        strPath = "C:/Users/" & Environ("username") & "/ZZZ/Office_K - Jobs" & strPath
    Else
        strPath = strPath
    End If
    
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "/", "\") & "\"
    
    
    strPath = GetFolder(strPath)
    
    ' count number of selected sheets in workbook
    ' MAYBE ADD IN A CHECK TO MAKE SURE MORE THAN ONE SHEET IS SELECTED
    iShts = Application.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count
    iOrig = Application.ActiveSheet.Index
    
    ' Capture the selected sheets into a Sheets Collection
    ' ...this is a collection, NOT an array
    Set coSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    
    ' call up user form
    ' and determine what button is pressed
    frmPrintPDFs.Show
    Select Case frmPrintPDFs.Tag
        Case 0: Exit Sub
        Case 1: Call singlePDF
        Case 2: Call multPDFs
    End Select
    
    ' to finish, activate the first (single) sheet of the selected group
    'j = coSheets(1).Index
    Worksheets(iOrig).Activate

End Sub


Public Sub multPDFs()
'==================================================================
' Subordinate subroutine used by the above macro.
' Creates multiple PDF files (one for each selected worksheet)
'==================================================================
    ' select a previously UNSELECTED sheet
    ' this stopped working for some reason, Jan. 2024.
    'Worksheets(j + 1).Activate
    ' FEB 2024...when all worksheets in book are selected,
    ' I think this is causing all sheets to print multiple times.
    Worksheets(1).Activate

    'SetPrinter

    ' ========================================
    ' Loop through each selected worksheet
    '
    ' For some reason, to get the selected sheets to print as individual PDFs
    ' you have to store them in a collection
    ' and not just "For Each ws In *.selectedsheets
    ' ========================================
    
    For i = 1 To iShts

        strSht = i & "_" & coSheets(i).Name
        strPDF = strPath & "\" & strSht

        With coSheets(i)
            ' select a cell to make sure no charts are selected before printing
            .Activate
            .Range("A1").Select

            ' call to sub in seperate module
            ' "Recalc" sub forces all equations to recalculate the activated worksheet to make sure everything updates
            Call Recalc

            ' print the worksheet
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=strPDF, _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `C:/Users/` should be `C:\Users\` ?

Comment: I don't THINK that's an issue here.

The "user" routine was included because I used to deal with files that could be either on a hard drive, or up in the cloud. Right now, I'm just dealing with local files.

And the replace statement should be handling that, anyway.

strPath = Replace(strPath, "/", "\") & "\"

Thanks for the inut!

Comment: In my M365 test results, there is a slight difference from your post. Regardless of the selected order of worksheets, the generated three PDF files contain all three worksheets. Anyway, please try to change `.Activate` to `.Select`. It works well for me.